# Can I change the reference of a global variable inside of a closure?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that references a global variable I can not change. Is it possible to modify the reference target for a specific invocation?

The offending code is in an external library and not in my control.

```js
const globalValue = 'something'

const foo = () => {
  console.log(globalValue)
}
```

I would like to patch the function so `globalValue` is referencing something else. Something like this:

```js
(() => {
  const globalValue = 'something else'
  foo()
})()
```

The above won't work, of course, but I'd like to be able to ensure `foo` in this context would log "something else" rather than the original "something".

Is there some JavaScript magic I can use to do that?

EDIT: This is also a contrived minimal case to help find an answer. In my actual case the `globalValue` is `window` and is pointing to the wrong `window` reference for my very weird use case.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Maybe there's a different solution to the main problem.

Comment: An external library is referencing `window` in their code. I have a weird use case where I need to inject that code into an iframe on the same domain. The `window` reference remains the parent's `window` reference and not the frame, which sadly breaks everything.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have any kind of dynamic scoping of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps, you can pass as argument the value of the variable

```js
let globalValue = 'something';

const f1 = (g = globalValue) => {
    console.log(g)
}

const f2 = () => {
    globalValue = 'something else';
    f1(globalValue);    
}

f1();
f2();
```